# SharePoint 2007 version history to track changes in InfoPath form

Tags: infopath, form, version-history

How do I make SharePoint 2007 versionning to keep track those fields from a InfoPath form that is set as columns?

Scenario:
I created a InfoPath form with 3 fields where 2 of the fields I make it available as columns in SharePoint sites. After publishing the form to the SharePoint form library, I see the following columns - a 'title' column plus the 2 columns from the InfoPath form. However, when I make changes to the any or both of the 2 columns, it was not recorded into the version history.

May I know what are the steps to make the 2 columns changes to be recorded into the version history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After when you make the 2 fields from your InfoPath available as columns for SharePoint, you still need to create 2 calculated columns inside your SharePoint form library for each of the columns that you promoted to the library as column.

Suppose one of the available column is called 'status', then in your Sharepoint form library, create a calculated column called 'status_version' and select the 'status' from the "Insert Columns" list box to the "Formula" list box. Do this again for your another column (since you mention you promoted 2 columns but if you have 20 columns, you will need to do it 20 times.)